# Mark new tag in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2,

I have set it up so I can add a new tag if it does not exist,

I am also using twitter bootstrap,
If a tag does not exist I want to mark it as a new tag, to do so I prepend the text with `'<span class="label label-important">New</span> '` this as my select2 initializer.

```
$('#newVideoCategory').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select a category...',
        data: categories,
        createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
            if ($(data).filter(function () {
                return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
                return {id: term, text: '<span class="label label-important">New</span> ' + term};
            }
        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            $(categories).each(function () {
                if (this.id == element.val()) {
                    callback(this);
                    return;
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Now this works great

[image: Marked as new tag]

Unless what I have entered for the tag exists as part of the markup for that label
[image: Error marked as new tag]

From what I have gathered I need to overwrite either the `formatResult`, `formatSelection`, or `matcher`.

That's what I got from the documentation, but I don't understand how I need to alter it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for posting (and answering) the question! I think I've found a simpler way to solve this:

```
...
createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
    if ($(data).filter(function() {
        return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
    }).length === 0) {
        return {id:term, text: term, isNew: true};
    }
},
formatResult: function(term) {
    if (term.isNew) {
        return '<span class="label label-important">New</span> ' + term.text;
    }
    else {
        return term.text;
    }
},
...
```

You can return any object from the `createSearchChoice()` function, so just add in a field telling `formatResult()` that it's a new item.

This way, the text of the returned item is just the text you want, and `formatResult()` is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Ah,
Got it by overwriting the `formatResult` function.

Basically what we do is check if the first characters are our `newTagMark` if it is, then we strip that off, apply the matching logic, then prepend it again to spit it out.

The bulk of the logic is actually just a copy and paste of select2's internal `markMatch` function.

```
var newTagMark = '<span class="label label-important">New</span> ';

$('#newVideoCategory').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a category...',
    data: categories,
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function () {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {id: term, text: newTagMark + term};
        }
    },
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        $(categories).each(function () {
            if (this.id == element.val()) {
                callback(this);
                return;
            }
        })
    },
    formatResult: function(result, container, query) {
        var text = result.text;
        var term = query.term;
        var markup=[];
        var marked = false;
        if(text.substr(0, newTagMark.length) == newTagMark){
            text = text.substr(newTagMark.length);
            markup.push(newTagMark);
        }

        var match=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()),
                tl=term.length;
        if (match<0) {
            markup.push(text);
            return;
        }

        markup.push(text.substring(0, match));
        markup.push("<span class='select2-match'>");
        markup.push(text.substring(match, match + tl));
        markup.push("</span>");
        markup.push(text.substring(match + tl, text.length));
        return markup.join("");
    }
});
```

Comment: With your code, added new tags have the text `newTagMark + term` don't they?

Answer (score 0):

A solution including the marking of matches is the following:

```
...
createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
    if ($(data).filter(function() {
        return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
    }).length === 0) {
        return {id:term, text: term, isNew: true};
    }
},
formatResult: function (result, container, query, escapeMarkup) {
    var markup=[];
    window.Select2.util.markMatch(this.text(result), query.term, markup, escapeMarkup);
    var text = markup.join("");
    if (result.isNew) {
        text = '<span class="label label-important">NEW</span> ' + text;
    }
    return text;
},
...
```